# Minitest 4.7.5 error in bundler when starting rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm brand new to rails, and litelarry am trying to set up a helloworld app to get my feet wet.

I installed homebrrew, ruby build and rbenv. I installed pow, and then unistalled it. basically played around, and then worked out how to make an application, and wonderful. I created helloworld.

I know minitest (5.0.8, 4.3.2) is installed in my home directory.

I cd into the hellowworld directory, and try to make the app active by typing rails -s.

I get this minitest error?

```
/Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-      1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find minitest-4.7.5 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.3.4/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:74:in `setup'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.3.4/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:103:in `check'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.3.4/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:109:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.3.4/lib/rubygems_executable_plugin.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.4/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `call'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.4/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `block in run'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.4/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `each'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.4/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `run'
from /Users/smithy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:10:in `<main>'
```

As far as I can see it relates to bundler, minitest4.7.5 is missing which I get. BUT how do I see that minitest 5.0 etc is installed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 38):

Per this link regarding [bundler version 1.5.0](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2780), you should upgrade your bundler to version 1.5.1 or higher to fix a nasty little bug that surfaces with default gems in Ruby 1.9 and 2.0. I simply ran ***gem update bundler*** before running ***bundle install*** and everything seems fine now.

Comment: Confirmed to work. Travis CI currently has Bundler 1.5.0 installed with Ruby 2.1.0, and I getting it to `gem update bundler` before starting the build fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @user1796994: This entire issue revolved around a bug in bundler 1.5.0 and the fix is available in any version of bundler after 1.5.1, so you should just use the latest version of bundler and you'll be fine.

Comment: I had the same problem and the same solution, with ruby 2.1.0